# Problem Installing and configuring PostgreSQL

Tags: 11.04, postgresql

I am a newbie here and to the server administration. A couple of days back I have registered a server with [Hetzner](http://www.hetzner.de/en/) with Ubuntu 11.04.

I intend to work with PostgreSQL, for which I have installed from source after failing to install using apt-get. The installation as such doesn't fail, but the PostgreSQl service doesn't start automatically or when I try to start it manually. It fails with the following error message when I try to do anything with it:

```
manager@Ubuntu-1104-natty-32-minimal:~$ sudo su postgres -c psql template1
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This was the error I was getting when I had installed PostgreSQL using apt-get and I re-installed it from source. The following is the output I got when I installed it from source. This confirms that the PostgreSQL is indeed installed.

```
make -C config install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/manager/postgresql-9.0.4/config'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/pgsql/lib/pgxs/config'
/bin/sh ../config/install-sh -c -m 755 ./install-sh '/usr/local/pgsql/lib/pgxs/config/install-sh'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/manager/postgresql-9.0.4/config'
PostgreSQL installation complete.
```

But, doesn't the service starts automatically? It doesn't here:

```
manager@Ubuntu-1104-natty-32-minimal:~$ ps auxw | grep post
manager   6734  0.0  0.0   4156   868 pts/0    S+   14:10   0:00 grep --color=auto post
```

This is taking a toll on my patience and confidence. Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Answering my own question. This is kinda annoying, the first question on any StackExchange site doesn't go well for me.

I had already done this, but somehow worked this time. Did this:

1. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
2. sudo apt-get purge postgresql*
3. sudo apt-get -f install
4. sudo apt-get install postgresql

Works like a charm.

Note: adding the * in the purge command will purge all packages that begin with postgresql

Comment: Just want to point out that if you have `perl: warning: Setting locale failed` when installing postgresql, it could cause the installation fail to create a new cluster, so the postgresql server won't start. Fixing that locale problem and reinstalling postgresql with the above instruction worked for me.

Comment: That worked like a charm for me! Thank you very much, I now have 9.5 installed when I originally installed 9.3 but wanted to switch. In the switch the install and reinstall didn't work very well.

Answer (score 6):

I too faced this problem with Hetzner and very annoying. Here is how I solved it
Tip: Looked at some pg package scripts

`sudo apt-get purge postgresql*` # ending * is important

`sudo apt-get install postgresql`

I suspect either Hetzner's 11.04 image is buggy or it's Ubuntu's .deb (unlikely though).

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen this error on launchpad in associtiation with Natty. The same issue has been raised as a [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgresql-common/+bug/193696) for Hardy and got a fix. So following that logic I would expect it to be a bug and it is probably best practice to file a bug on launchpad.

Looking further into it I found 2 interesting (yet old) topics showing the exact same error that seem worth looking into:

[This topic](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-user@lists.debian.org/msg444060.html) from 2006 is talking about the exact same problem and claims that

`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.1 stop`

`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.1 start`

`psql template1`

works.

On [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=869080) there is a topic from 2008 about the same error and has a status 'solved'. Please have a look at the many suggestions in that topic.

Answer (score 2):

psql is the cli client, it does not start the PostgreSQL server. To start the server, you should use:

`/etc/init.d/postgresql start`

then you can connect to it using psql.

To have PostgreSQL start on boot, you should do the following:

`update-rc.d postgresql enable`

You might also take a look at this:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-controlling-access-to-linux-services.html

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu 14.04, I was having similar problems and couldn't get it working using the above solutions. In the end I found my answer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1396862).

a) I ran this command `aptitude search postgresql|grep ^i` in terminal and got the following results back:

```
i   postgresql                      - object-relational SQL database (supported 
i A postgresql-9.3                  - object-relational SQL database, version 9.
i A postgresql-client-9.3           - front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.3     
i A postgresql-client-common        - manager for multiple PostgreSQL client ver
i A postgresql-common               - PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
```

b) Then: `sudo aptitude purge postgresql postgresql-9.3 postgresql-common`

c) Finally: `sudo aptitude install postgresql`

Everything now works fine.