# Unable to run PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, sql

I followed an instruction on how to setup Ubuntu 10.04 with [PostgresSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)

```
$ psql
```

Or this:

```
lucid@ubuntu:~$ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
[sudo] password for lucid: 
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: Take a look at postgres documentation at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config.html In particular, sections 18.3.1 and 18.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the command should be

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

If that does not work, tell us more about your configuration.

Comment: When I type this command, I get this "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"? -- same as the error in my question

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/42013/problem-installing-and-configuring-postgresql